# asp.net IIS 7.5 Cookieless page not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I have deployed my asp.net web application to a test IIS 7.5 server (same machine in fact). the application works fine in visual studio 2010. I am using cookieless authentication. when i open the deployed site and it is redirecting the user to the main page after login, i get a page not found error.
Any ideas why this might be happening?

thanks
Damo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code behind the login page i had the following.

```
string Redirectport = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
    RedirectURL = "http://localhost:" + Redirectport + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/Main.aspx");
```

i had to change the word localhost to the actual pc name. I will make this part of the webconfig.

is this the way to do this. i thought it would of worked with localhost??

thanks
Damo